# Transformation Matrix (roll inversed?)

Tags: java, processing, transformation

this is a part of the code, that visualizes the rotation of my arduino. 
Unfortunatly the roll is "inversed"... It gets called each tick with some updated values.

By inversed I mean: If I roll the arduino to the right, the visualization rolls it to the left and vice versa.

```
pushMatrix(); // begin object
translate(width/4, height/4); // set position
float c1 = cos(radians(roll));
float s1 = sin(radians(roll));
float c2 = cos(radians(pitch));
float s2 = sin(radians(pitch));
float c3 = cos(radians(yaw));
float s3 = sin(radians(yaw));
applyMatrix( c2*c3, s1*s3+c1*c3*s2, c3*s1*s2-c1*s3, 0,
             -s2  , c1*c2         , c2*s1         , 0,
             c2*s3, c1*s2*s3-c3*s1, c1*c3+s1*s2*s3, 0,
             0    , 0             , 0             , 1);

drawArduino();
popMatrix(); // end of object
```

does anybody see the mistake I made?

this is how I compute the values I pass into the matrix:

```
int aix, aiy, aiz, tax, tay, taz;
int gix, giy, giz;
float ax, ay, az;
float gx, gy, gz;
float roll, pitch, heading;

CurieIMU.readMotionSensor(aix, aiy, aiz, gix, giy, giz);

// convert from raw data to gravity and degrees/second units
ax = convertRawAcceleration(aix);
ay = convertRawAcceleration(aiy);
az = convertRawAcceleration(aiz); //acceleration for 2g
gx = convertRawGyro(gix);
gy = convertRawGyro(giy);
gz = convertRawGyro(giz);

// update the filter, which computes orientation
filter.updateIMU(gx, gy, gz, ax, ay, az);


// print the heading, pitch and roll
roll = filter.getRoll();
pitch = filter.getPitch();
heading = filter.getYaw();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to invert the roll value: this can be done by subtracting the roll value from the maximum value it can have

```
inverted = max - current
```

I see you're using degrees, so here's demo you can run of how to invert the value assuming your maximum value is 360:

- click and drag to rotate
- press a key to invert rotation

```js
var roll, pitch, yaw;

var maxRoll = 360;
var invertRoll = false;


function setup(){
  createCanvas(300,300);
  rectMode(CENTER);
}
function draw(){
  var rollValue = roll;
  if(invertRoll){
    
    rollValue = maxRoll - roll;
    
    background(0);
  }else{
    background(255);
  }
  
  background(invertRoll ? color(0) : color(255));
  translate(width * 0.5, height * 0.5);
  rotate(radians(rollValue));
  rect(0,0,100,100);
}

function mouseDragged(){
  roll = map(mouseX,0,width,0,360);
}

function keyPressed(){
  invertRoll = !invertRoll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.5/p5.min.js"></script>
```

If it helps, here's a Processing test sketch based on your snippet above:

```
float roll, pitch, yaw;

float maxRoll = 360;
boolean invertRoll;

void setup() {
  size(400,400,P3D);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);

  pushMatrix(); // begin object
  translate(width/4, height/4); // set position

  float rollValue = roll;

  if(invertRoll) rollValue = maxRoll - roll;

  float c1 = cos(radians(rollValue));
  float s1 = sin(radians(rollValue));

  float c2 = cos(radians(pitch));
  float s2 = sin(radians(pitch));
  float c3 = cos(radians(yaw));
  float s3 = sin(radians(yaw));
  applyMatrix( c2*c3, s1*s3+c1*c3*s2, c3*s1*s2-c1*s3, 0, 
    -s2, c1*c2, c2*s1, 0, 
    c2*s3, c1*s2*s3-c3*s1, c1*c3+s1*s2*s3, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1);

  drawArduino();
  popMatrix(); // end of object
}

void drawArduino() {
  box(100);
}

void mouseDragged(){
  roll = map(mouseX,0,width,0,360);
}

void keyPressed(){
  invertRoll = !invertRoll;
}
```

Another option would be scale the axis you want to invert by -1
then translate to offset back to the position you want to draw at.